# Standard deviation (percentage)

Tags: statistics

I'm writing an exam tomorrow and I just can't figure out how to do this sum.
I did the standard deviation already now all I need to know is how to determine the percentage of workers. Sounds weird but I will give you the question

---

> Sample of weekly wages earned by $10$ workers
>
> $2250, 2250, 3000, 3300, 3300, 3600, 3900, 4350, 5250$
>
> Calculate the mean, which is $3555$.
>
> Calculate the standard deviation, which is $900.12$.

Now this is where I can't figure out how to do it .

> Determine the percentage of workers which lie within ONE standard deviation of the mean?

Please help me I don't know what formula to use for this question

Comment: It is trivial! Take $\mu\pm\sigma$ and count how many workers lie in that interval!

Comment: You are missing a wage. You said there are 10 workers', but you listed 9 wages.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise illustrating the Empirical Rule:

To start, let's get the correct mean $\bar X = 3466.667$ and standard
deviation $S = 961.7692.$ (Please do some checking here. Did one of us type the observations incorrectly,
or did you incorrectly compute $\bar X$ and $S$.)

Then observations 3000, 3300, 3300, 3600, 3900, and 4350 (six of the nine)
are within one standard deviation of the mean. (Please verify this: Find the
endpoints of the interval $\bar X \pm S$. Then check which observations
fall within the interval.)

So the desired proportion
is $6/9  \approx 66.7\%$ (The Empirical Rule suggests this proportion
is often 'about 68%`, so your percentage is pretty close. The ER is an *approximate* rule;
don't necessarily expect exact results.)

For reference, computations from R statistical software are as follows:

```
x = c(2250,2250,3000,3300,3300,3600,3900,4350,5250)
a = mean(x);  s = sd(x)
a;  s
## 3466.667      # average
## 961.7692      # SD
x[abs(a-x)<=s]   # list of observations within one SD of average
## 3000 3300 3300 3600 3900 4350
pm = c(-1,1);  a + pm*s
## 2504.897 4428.436
mean(abs(x-a)<s) # proportion of obs within one SD of avg
## 0.6666667
```

One more thing: Now, to consolidate you understanding, please try this: The ER suggests that about 95% of
the observations fall within *two* standard deviations of the mean. How
many of your observations fall within the interval $\bar X \pm 2S ?$